# Linear algebra proof of $M(S \circ T) = M(S)M(T)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I must provide proof of the following statement:
If $T,S \in L(V)$, then taking matrices with respect to $B$ (which is any basis of $V$), $M(S \circ T) = M(S)M(T)$

Comment: Do you know how the matrix coefficients $M(S)_{i,j}$ are defined?

Comment: Let's see, if L(V) is a set of all vector spaces which could have any basis (a pretty vague description in its own right), and T and S are its subspaces, then I just should show that composition of two matrices each based on separate subspaces is equal to single matrix based on composition of subspaces? I was just not sure how to write it down in correct math form.

Comment: @Stewart It seems you get the definitions wrong. I suppose that $V$ is a vector space; $L(V)$ is the algebra of linear endomorphisms of $V$, hence $S,T$ are linear maps $V\to V$; $M(S)$ is the matrix of the linear map with respect to $B$.

Comment: @s.harp, yes, each matrix has elements ranging from $M(S)_{0,0}$ to $M(S)_{n,m}$ if we are talking about matrix of undefined size, one set of coefficients for columns and the other for rows.

Comment: @Stewart Thats not really a definition, you are just saying that to a matrix you can assign coefficients indexed by two numbers. If you have a linear map $S$, how do you get the coefficients of $M(S)$?

Comment: @s.harp Well, I know that linear map involves mapping between two vector spaces, so if basis of first vector space goes from $e_0$ to $e_n$, and the basis of second vector space goes from $f_0$ to $f_m$, said linear map will result in a matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix}a_{00} & ... & a_{0n}\\... & ... & ... \\ a_{m0} & ... & a_{mn}\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Lets be more concrete. First we are considering maps from a vector space $V$ into itself. Now if we have a basis $B=\{b_1,..,b_n\}$ we can associate a matrix to a linear map $S: V \to V$ by defining the coefficients of the matrix $M(S)$ from the following equality: $\sum_i M(S)_{i,j}b_i = S(b_j)$. This equation uniquely determines all the coefficients of the matrix $M(S)$. Now if you want to find the matrix coefficients of $M(T \circ S)$ what do you look at?

Comment: @s.harp Okay, so if we have $\sum_i M( S )_{ i,j } b_i = S( b_j )$ and $\sum_i M( T )_{ i,j } b_i = T( b_j )$, then we can express the equation as:

$M(S \circ T) = \sum_i M( S \circ T )_{ i,j } b_i = (S \circ T)( b_j ) = (S(T( b_j )) = S( b_j )T( b_j ) =\sum_i M( S )_{ i,j } b_i\sum_i M( T )_{ i,j } b_i = M(S)M(T)$

Comment: This part $S(T(b_j))=S(b_j)T(b_j)$ is not true, but you started at the right point. The correct way to continue is: $S(T(b_j))=S(\sum_k M(T)_{k,j} b_k)$. Now since S is a linear map, you can pull out the sum and the coefficients: $S(T(b_j))=\sum_k M(T)_{k,j} S(b_k) = \sum_k M(T)_{k,j} \sum_i M(S)_{i,k} b_i = \sum_{i} (\sum_k M(S)_{i,k} M(T)_{k,j}) b_i$. If you compare the part in the brackets of the last term with matrix multiplication, you will see that it is equal to $(M(S)\cdot M(T))_{i,j}$. Then the equation has become: $\sum_i M(S \circ T)_{i,j} b_i= \sum_i (M(S) \cdot M(T))_{i,j} b_i$.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the fact that for any $v\in V$, the matrix of $T$ with respect to $B$ applied to $v$ expressed in base $B$ produces $T(v)$ expressed in base $B$.

Comment: Okay, so once I go with that statement for both S and T, which would be the best way to show the expanded form of $M(S \circ T) = M(S)M(T)$ equation?